# Decode frame sequence exception while NVIDIA GPU is used for H265 video decoding acceleration

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu, hardware-acceleration, h.265

We are using **NVIDIA GPUs** (model: GTX1050TI) to accelerate H.265 video decoding and rendering, and DXVA2 hardware acceleration is used. The version of FFmpeg is 4.2.2. If the video is played for a long time, there will be **frame skipping forward** (that is, the video frame of the first few seconds will appear when it is played in normal order), and it will always exist after it appears, and it will not heal itself.
We checked the rendering and playback timing of each frame and found that no forward jump occurred. Therefore, the data decoded by the GPU may be incorrect. We also used AMD GPUs for comparison tests, but **this is not the case with AMD GPUs**.
Has anyone been in the same situation or can anyone help?

Comment: Hello, why would you use a version that's this outdated (from 2019)? Please share also the command(s) you're running.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I know the ffmpeg version is outdated,  but this is the version used at work, and replacing the new ffmpeg can be expensive.

Comment: Also, I don't run the code from the command line. Do you have any other possible reasons for skipping forward frames other than versioning?

Comment: In that case you have StackOverflow where you can share the code, but I see there's already a closed cross-posted question without any code. People usually don't like guessing here. Nor cross-posting.

Comment: ffmpeg is free for commercial use: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14802/can-i-use-ffmpeg-in-a-commercial-product It is not "expensive" to upgrade ffmpeg, it is free. Speak w/ your IT folks about getting the current version.